# least upper bound lubAB=lubA*lubB (Revised)

Tags: real-analysis

I just finished proving lub(A+B)=lubA+lubB and was wondering what the proof was for lubAB=lubA*lubB this? How could I show this? Where A and B are positive and A*B= {ab | a in A and b in B|

My previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547702/least-upper-bound-lubab-lubalubb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\operatorname{lub}(A)\operatorname{lub}(B)\geq\operatorname{lub}(AB)$:

Suppose not for the sake of contradiction. Then, since $\operatorname{lub}(A)\operatorname{lub}(B)<\operatorname{lub}(AB)$, there is some $q\in AB$ such that $q>\operatorname{lub}(A)\operatorname{lub}(B)$. Now, for any $q\in AB$, there is some $a\in A$, $b\in B$ such that $ab=q$. But, since $\operatorname{lub}(A)\geq a$, $\operatorname{lub}(B)\geq b$, $\operatorname{lub}(A)\operatorname{lub}(B)\geq ab=q$, a contradiction.

$\operatorname{lub}(A)\operatorname{lub}(B)\leq\operatorname{lub}(AB)$:

Suppose not for the sake of contradiction. Then, there exists some $a\in A$, $b\in B$ such that $ab>\operatorname{lub}(AB)$. But, $ab\in AB$, so this is a contradiction.